# Add solid color legend key for item which has different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I find matplotlib to be one of the mot confusing libraries to figure out :(

I am using the scatter function of an axis to plot some points, and each point has its own weight associated with it that controls the opacity...

```
colors = [(*c[:3], w.item() / 1) for w in weight]
ax.scatter(gen, samples, c=colors, s=10, marker="*", label="$\\tilde{x}$", zorder=-100)
ax.legend
```

The problem is that the color in the legend appears to be a random color from the `colors` array. Sometimes it is translucent because some of the colors in the scatter are nearly translucent. I would like the color in the legend to be solid, while keeping the variable colors in the scatterplot.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Do these, `gen,  samples,  colors`, have equal length?

Comment: yes they do, I think it would throw an error if they had a different length

Comment: I guess the values in `colors` are used to get colors from the default colormap.

Comment: yes I am aware that it is probably using one of the colors in the color array. I am asking how to make it not do that

Comment: But which of the colors should it have? I thought the problem was the alpha value, not the color choice.

Comment: In `scatter()`, if you add option `cmap='tab20b'`, it should produce better output.

Comment: the problem is the alpha value, I want to show an alpha value of 1.0 in the legend, right now it is random, probably based off of the first color in the list. I will try what you said @swatchai

Comment: @switchai, that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Changing only the alpha value of the legend handle turned out to be more difficult than expected (the obvious way `item.set_alpha(1)` creates problems with some of the colors that will be nearly invisible). But you can set the handle color, giving the legend a uniform appearance:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#fake data generation
import numpy as np
n = 10
np.random.seed(1234)
gen = np.random.randint(1, 10, n)
samples = np.random.randint(10, 50, n)
colors = np.random.rand(n, 4)
#reduce the alpha values for demonstration purposes
colors[:, 3] = colors[:, 3]/3


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

ax.scatter(gen, samples, c=colors, s=70, marker="o", label="$\\tilde{y}$", zorder=-100)
ax.scatter(samples, gen, c=colors, s=50, marker="x", label="$\\tilde{x}$", zorder=-100)

l = ax.legend()

for item in l.legendHandles:
    item.set_color("black")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]